# How do I identify directories with growing disk space usage in Ubuntu and Btrfs?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space, btrfs

How do I identify directories with growing disk space usage in Ubuntu and Btrfs?

Sometimes I notice that disk usage has increased considerably but I don't know which directory is responsible for the increase. Tools like du only tell you current usage not the change in usage.

How do I tell which directories are most responsible for a big change in disk usage?

Comment: hit the windows key, type `analy` and you will see the icon of "Disk Usage Analyzer"; it will display disk usage graphically - maybe one step towards what you want?

Comment: You can analyse the result of `btrfs subvolume find-new`. It will show you all the modifed/created files since the specified generation (but not the removed files or copied files using COW). A generation is a batch of modifications commited on the disk regularly (e.g. 30s, depending of your system setting), or after a sync. You can put the generation of a previous snapshot or other. The command above will tell you which is your current generation number.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Btrfs Snapshot Disk Usage Analyzer ([btsdu](https://github.com/rkapl/btsdu)) between snapshots.

```
btsdu -p /snapshots/old_snapshot /snapshots/new_snapshot
```

Comment: Please edit and expand your answer

Comment: "Claims" implies you do not believe it does, making this a comment, not an answer. You can use the EDIT button the fix this and make it an actual answer.